# Spring: Get the list of beans injected into a bean

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking for a way to list the beans that are injected into a particular Spring bean at runtime.  For example, given these two classes:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestComponent testComponent;

    private final TestService testService;

    public TestController(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class TestService {

}
```

and

```
@Component
public class TestComponent {

}
```

The list of beans for the `TestController` class should return:

- `TestService` (injected via constructor)
- `TestComponent` (injected via `@Autowired` annotation)

Is there an existing Spring helper/utility that can return this information for me?

Comment: Do you need it for debug purpose ?

Comment: No, this is not for debugging.

Comment: Ok, so i suppose spring boot actuator /beans path is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Just wondering what do you need this information for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query names of dependent beans from the `ConfigurableBeanFactory` for a given bean name with the method `getDependenciesForBean()`. So in your example the code could look like

```java
try (ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication.class)) {
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = app.getBeanFactory();
    String[] dependencies = beanFactory.getDependenciesForBean("testController");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dependencies)); // [testService, testComponent]
}
```

The problem hereby is that you only work on *names* of beans. So to make the code generic for a given bean instance you would have to find out the name of the bean (which can be non-unique) and also when getting the actual injected beans for these names it can be possible that you don't get the same instances (because of `@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` on the bean definition).